# downloading sql

Tags: sql-server

i want to download sql server 2014 to my laptop,i tried many websites but couldnt find how can some one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you not try the Microsoft website?

You can get the free Express version here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42299

If you want another version you will need to either create a Microsoft account to download the Developer edition or pay lots of money to Microsoft to get the Standard or Enterprise editions.